# Django multiple admin modifying the same databases

Tags: django, database, admin

i'm a total noob in django and just wondering if it's possible for an admin doing a same thing at the same time ? the only thing i get after looking at the django documentation is that it is possible to have two admins, but is it possible for the admins to do a task in the same databases at the same time ?

thanks for any help

Comment: welcome, can you just try it, what troubles do you have with it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't made it clear that what do you actually want but:

If by admin you mean a superuser then yes you can have as many admins as you want.

Admins can change anything in database at the same time, but if you mean changing a specific row of a specific table at the same time, its not possible because of these reasons:

- Its kinda impossible to save something at the same time. when both admins tries to save anything, the last request will be saved (the first one will be saved too but it changes to the last request)
- and if there is any important data in database, you should block any other accesses to that row till the first user has done his job and saved the changes. (imagine a ticket reservation website which has to block any other users to be allowed to order the same ticket number till user finishes the order or cancel it.)

Also if you mean 2 different django projects using a single database, then its another yes. Basically they are like 2 different admins and all above conditions works for them too.

Comment: yes that's what i meant superuser, it's in the same project same databases but different table (one user the other one is city)

Comment: @user3646742 Yes they can access database and make changes at the same time.